# Validação Campo E-mail's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dificuldade de implementação de validação de E-mail, de um campo que recebe vários,quando for e-mail valido destaca-lo e separa-lo por ponto e vírgula.

```
function IsEmail(email){
    var exclude=/[^@-.w]|^[_@.-]|[._-]{2}|[@.]{2}|(@)[^@]*1/;
    var check=/@[w-]+./;
    var checkend=/.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    if(((email.search(exclude) != -1)||(email.search(check)) == -1)||(email.search(checkend) == -1)){return false;}
    else {return true;}
}
```

Comment: É importante você marcar uma resposta, caso solucione seu problema, como aceita. Veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

```js
//recebido do input
var emailStr = "pedromartins@google.com,leocaracciolo@google.com,emanuel@google.com,invalido@,invalidotambem";

//declarando variavel
var validos ="";

//divide emailStr em um array de strings separados pelo 'separador esvirgula'
var emails = emailStr.split(',')

//use a que mais lhe apatecer
var regex = /^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$/;

//o loop  para iteração com o array
for (var i = 0; i <= emails.length; i++) {

     // se amail diferente de nulo e satisfaz a regex, acumula os validos na variável 'validos' concatenando com ; (ponto e virgula)
     if( emails[i] != "" && regex.test(emails[i])){
         validos += (emails[i]) +";" ;  
     }
}

//função substr para retirar ultimo ; (ponto e virgula)
console.log(validos.substr(0,(validos.length - 1)));
```

**Para fazer uso com função:**

```js
function validarEmails() {

  var validos ="";
  var inValidos ="";
  
  var emailStr = document.getElementById('emails').value;
  
  var emails = emailStr.split(',');
  
  var regex = /^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$/;
  
  for (var i = 0; i <= emails.length; i++) {

       if( emails[i] != "" && regex.test(emails[i])){
           validos += (emails[i]) +";" ;  
       }
  }
  
  validos = (validos.substr(0,(validos.length - 1)));

  console.log("validos: " +validos);
}
```

```html
  <input id='emails' placeholder="emails separados por virgulas">
  <button type='submit' onclick="validarEmails()">Validar!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usar [expressões regulares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) é provavelmente a melhor forma. Podes ver uns quantos testes [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/ghvj4gy9/embedded/result,js/) (retirado de [chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/fast/forms/resources/ValidityState-typeMismatch-email.js&sq=package:chromium&type=cs))

```
function validarEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Tens aqui alguns exemplos de expressões regulares que aceitam unicode:

```
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

Mas tem em mente que não se deve confiar apenas na validação do JavaScript. JavaScript pode ser facilmente desativado. Isso deve ser validado no lado do servidor também.

Está aqui um exemplo disso em ação:

```js
function validarEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validar() {
  var $result = $("#result");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  $result.text("");

  if (validarEmail(email)) {
    $result.text(email + " é válido :)");
    $result.css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $result.text(email + " não é válido :(");
    $result.css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("#validar").bind("click", validar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Introduz o seu endereço eletrónico:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validar'>Validar!</button>
</form>

<h2 id='result'></h2>
```

Comment: Certo,contudo esse INPUT vai recebe vários email's no mesmo campo,como serie essa implementação.